# $ rspec /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby2.1’: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. When I run rspec I get this:

```
$ rspec

/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby2.1’: No such file or directory
```

but that's not my ruby version

```
$ ruby -v

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

Comment: have have you installed ruby?

Comment: `which rspec` are you using?

Comment: How do I check rspec version? I'm using ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]